# Cannot Navigate to VSTS url in Windows Server Machine

Tags: azure-devops, windows-server-2012

I have hosted a MVC application in IIS on Windows Server 2012. In my application i am trying to access VSTS But i am not able to do it.

I have tried navigating to the URL in IE of server , there also its not showing anything. Only a white screen is being displayed.

I have tried adding inbound and outbound rules as well for port 443 but nothing is working. In debug console , under network , it is sending only Get requests and it gets struck there only.
I have searched Net a lot but didn't find anything. Any help will be appreciated.

I am trying to access the VSTS using below code

```
 WorkItemStore workItemStore = null;
 Uri collectionUri = new Uri("https://microsoft.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");
 TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri);
 workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

 Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["*ProjectName*"];
 WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["Scenario"];
```

Comment: What corporate firewall do you have configured? It may be blocked at that level...

Comment: Is IE Enhanced Security Configuration turned on? (Server Manager > Local Server) If so, try to turn off it.

Comment: Yes , Enhanced Security Configuration is turned on. If i turn it off , will the application be able to access that link or we have to do anything else for that ?

Comment: I have disabled the enhanced security and now i am able to access the VSO in IE but in my application , still i am getting the same exception `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://microsoft.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.`

Comment: How do you access your VSTS in the application? What do you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to create tasks and scenarios based on some logic in VSO. It is working for VSTF in the same application but not for VSTS.I have updated my question with code. @starain-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Basic Authentication (or OAuth) is supported on your scenario (web app hosted on Azure that connects to Visual Studio Team Services).
Ditch the usage of the old TFS APIs (aka Object Model) and embrace the [VSTS REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview). Follow these steps:

- Create your Personal Access Token: a PAT will be used as the password, as for username you could use an empty string;
- For any HTTP request, pass in that Basic Auth headers containing your PAT: you could do it with any REST library of your choice, or you could leverage the VSTS specific .NET library called [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet), that uses the REST APIs underneath. With the latter follows this sample code for listing all Team Projects of your VSTS account (the ones the PAT have access to):

  ```
  using System.Net.Http;
  using System.Net.Http.Headers;
  string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", YOUR_PATH)));
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://accountname.visualstudio.com:");  //url of our account
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials); 
      //connect to the REST endpoint            
      HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("_apis/projects?stateFilter=All&api-version=1.0").Result;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the credential to authenticate to VSTS, enable "Alternate authentication credentials" for your account and update your code to following and then try again:

```
    WorkItemStore workItemStore = null;
    Uri collectionUri = new Uri("https://microsoft.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");
    NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("alternateusername","alternatepassword");
    BasicAuthCredential bac = new BasicAuthCredential(nc);
    TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri,bac);
    workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

    Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["*ProjectName*"];
    WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["Scenario"];
```

Comment: i have added `NetworkCredential` logic in my code but still same issue persists. I am able to work properly on my local but on server only i am facing issue.

Comment: @G.SAbhaypal Did you enable the alternate authentication credentials and then use it in your code?

Comment: i am in a corporate domain so i don't have that option enabled in my account profile in VSTS.

Comment: @G.SAbhaypal So you are authenticating to VSTS with Azure AD?

Comment: Yeah , guess so. Because server is an azure web server and my corporate id has default access on that server.

Comment: @G.SAbhaypal Can you try removing the "BasicAuthCredential" line and changing "NetworkCredential" to "AadCredential".

Comment: with "AadCredential" , i am getting that same exception even in local. With "NetworkCredential" only it is working fine. Before i haden't used any kind of credential code , i guess with application pool only i was able to connect to vstf.

Comment: @G.SAbhaypal What's vstf?

Comment: VSTF - visual studio team foundation @Eddie-MSFT

Comment: @G.SAbhaypal The authentication type is different between TFS(VSTS) and VSTS.  And if you are using VSTS, you should be able to enable the alternate authentication credentials even you use AD account. Can you check this by clicking your account in the VSTS web portal upper right corner and select "Security"?

Comment: Alternate authentication credentials 

warning: Personal access tokens are a more convenient and secure replacement for Alternate authentication credentials. Please use personal access tokens instead.

Alternate authentication credentials can be used to allow applications outside the browser access to the resources stored in your account.   



 
Alternate credentials are disabled on this account.       **The above text is getting displayed in my security tab under alternate authentication credentials**

Answer (score 0):

By default, regarding application hosted on IIS, it uses applicationpool identity if the authentication type isn't Windows authentication , which can’t access to your VSTS.

So you can specify the account to access your VSTS.

Simple code:

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("[user name]", "[password]");
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("[collection url]"), cred);
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

You also can change the identity of the application pool.

1. Open IIS Manager > Application Pools
2. Select the application pool > Advanced Settings (Actions pane)
3. For the Identity property, click … button
4. Select Build-in account option and select an account

On the other hand, regarding Enhanced Security Configuration, you can turn off it or add necessary sites to trust sites list if you don’t want to disable it. (It will prompt a dialogs that includes URLs)

[image]

Comment: the identity given in application pool is mine only. It can access vstf with that but not VSTS. So i will try adding `NetworkCredential` code and will update here. Thanks !!

Comment: @G.SAbhaypal Specify the application pool identity works fine for me.

Comment: i have already given application pool identity as mine. I have added above code also in my package but still i am getting same exception.In local its working completely fine. Any validation check for VSTS on server which i can do ? :(

Comment: @G.SAbhaypal Could you share a simple project one the OneDrive? Also provide the detail steps to host your project to IIS.